# How would you automatically retry a failed ajax call 3 times (synchronously)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to rerun a failed AJAX call 3 times. After the third attempt, I'd like to call a failed method. I don't want the AJAX calls to over run each other though.

What's the safest/best way to achieve this with what I'm working with?

I'm using a globalAjaxRequest method like so:

```
globalAjaxRequest(request, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        let ajaxRequest = null;

        if (request.url) {
            const ajaxOptions = {
                type: request.method ? request.method.toUpperCase() : 'POST',
                url: request.url,
                data: request.data || undefined,
                beforeSend: request.beforeSend,
                success: (data) => {
                    successCallback(data);
                },
                error: (data) => {
                    if (errorCallback) {
                        errorCallback(data);
                    }
                }
            };

            ajaxOptions.dataType = request.dataType || 'json';
            ajaxOptions.contentType = request.contentType || 'application/json; charset=utf-8';

            if (request.contentType) {
                ajaxOptions.data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(ajaxOptions.data));
            } else {
                ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(ajaxOptions.data);
            }

            ajaxRequest = $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
        }

        return ajaxRequest;
    }
}
```

Here's my attempt:

```
callAPI() {
    const callData = {
        url: '/callApi',
        data: {
            id: 'something'
        }
    };

    global.Utils.globalAjaxRequest(callData, (success) => {
        console.log('success');
        successMethod();
    }, (fail) => {
        for (let i = 1;; i++) {
            i <= 3 && setTimeout(() => {
                callAPI();
            }, 1000);

            if (i > 3) {
                failedMethod();
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}

callAPI();
```

Comment: $.ajax returns a Promise (and by extension so does your custom wrapper) so... why are you using callbacks? Why not just handle the rejection? Why synchronous?

Comment: So in success/fail, do I just chain then() three times? Do you have an example please? I've been tasked with running the same ajax call 3 times (even if it fails). On the third time I need to load another function

Comment: `$.ajax(ajaxOptions).catch(err => $.ajax(ajaxOptions)).catch(err => $.ajax(ajaxOptions)).catch(err=> { throw err; });` retries twice before giving up and rejecting with the last error. I'm sure you can figure out how to make it try 3x...

Comment: Well, don't (try to) do it synchronously. Read up on what the first A in ajax stands for. Do it *sequentially* by making a recursive call in the error handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can't retry an asynchronous operation such as `$.ajax()` synchronously, so I'll assume that you just meant you want to automatically retry sequentially if it fails.

Here's a generic retry function for `$.ajax()`:

```
// general purpose promise delay, useful when you want to delay a promise chain
function pDelay(t, v) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, t, v);
    });
}

// three arguments:
//   options: value for $.ajax(options) - does not support other forms of calling $.ajax()
//   delay: amount of time in ms to delay before each retry (can be 0 if you want)
//   retries: number of times to retry, defaults to 3 if you don't pass it
$.ajaxRetry = function(options, delay, retries) {
    // default value for retries is 3 if the argument is not passed
    let retriesRemaining = retriesRemaining !== undefined ? retriesRemaining: 3;

    let opts = Object.assign({}, options);

    function run() {
        return $.ajax(opts).catch(function(err) {
            --retriesRemaining;
            // don't fire this more than once
            delete opts.beforeSend;
            if (retriesRemaining > 0) {
                // try again after short delay
                return pDelay(delay).then(run);
            } else {
                // hit max retries, propagate error back to caller
                throw e;
            }
        });
    }
    return run();
}
```

FYI, this code assumes that "failure" in your case means that the promise that `$.ajax()` rejects.  If "failure" means something else (such as looking at some result you got), then you will have to insert that additional test into the retry loop or expose a callback where that additional test can be provided externally.

---

To integrate this into your wrapper, you could do this:

```
globalAjaxRequest(request, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        let ajaxRequest = null;

        if (request.url) {
            const ajaxOptions = {
                type: request.method ? request.method.toUpperCase() : 'POST',
                url: request.url,
                data: request.data || undefined,
                beforeSend: request.beforeSend,
            };

            ajaxOptions.dataType = request.dataType || 'json';
            ajaxOptions.contentType = request.contentType || 'application/json; charset=utf-8';

            if (request.contentType) {
                ajaxOptions.data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(ajaxOptions.data));
            } else {
                ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(ajaxOptions.data);
            }

            errorCallback = errorCallback || function(err) { throw err; };
            ajaxRequest = $.ajaxRetry(ajaxOptions, 0, 3).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
        }

        return ajaxRequest;
    }
}
```

---

FYI, it is kind of odd to take a promise interface and turn it back into plain callbacks.  It seems you should just get rid of `successCallback` and `errorCallback` let the caller use the returned promise.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this that uses a closure to keep a counter above the async request:

```
globalAjaxRequest(request, successCallback, errorCallback, maxRequests) {
        maxRequests = maxRequests || 1;
        var requests = 1;

        function ajaxRequest(request){

            if (request.url) {
                const ajaxOptions = {
                    type: request.method ? request.method.toUpperCase() : 'POST',
                    url: request.url,
                    data: request.data || undefined,
                    beforeSend: request.beforeSend,
                    success: (data) => {
                        successCallback(data);
                    },
                    error: (data) => {
                        if (requests < maxRequests){
                            requests++;
                            ajaxRequest(request);
                        } else if (errorCallback) {
                            errorCallback(data);
                        }
                    }
                };

                ajaxOptions.dataType = request.dataType || 'json';
                ajaxOptions.contentType = request.contentType || 'application/json; charset=utf-8';

                if (request.contentType) {
                    ajaxOptions.data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(ajaxOptions.data));
                } else {
                    ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(ajaxOptions.data);
                }
            return $.ajax(ajaxOptions)
        }

        ajaxRequest(request);
}
```